# React Router conditioning by Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-component

I'm using React Router for server side rendering and I'd like to run a special action on certain Route, actually on DefaultRoute. How should I create condition for that? I tried following code:

```
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var routes = [
    React.createElement(Route, {name: "root", path: "/", handler: Root},
        React.createElement(DefaultRoute, {handler: Default})
    )
]

var Default = React.createClass({
    displayName: "Default",
    render: function () {
        return React.createElement("h2", null, "Default");
    }
});

var Root = React.createClass({
    displayName: "App",
    render: function () {
        return (
            React.createElement(RouteHandler, null)
        );
    }
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    Router.run(routes, req.path, function (Root, state) {
        if (React.createElement(Root, null).constructor.displayName === 'Default'){
            //run specific action
        }   
    });
});
```

But I can't get the name of component this way. Is there any other way to recognize that I'm on Default Route??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (state.routes.length === 0 || state.routes[state.routes.length - 1].isDefault) { 
    // stuff here 
}
```

That's even better.

Comment: Very hackish way thought. Better have official API

Comment: That's right, but this question is older than react router 1.0, so there was no official API for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using React-Router for isomorphic server side routing.

The `state` prop in the callback of `Router.run` contains the active routes. You could do something like:

```js
// states.routes returns the nested routes that your path matches.
// This will return the last route. 
if (state.routes[state.routes.length-1].isDefault) {
  // stuff here
  // you also have access to the onEnter method and the handler (component) in the route too.
}
```

Check out the API documentation here: http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run. Good luck!